# Justify Content Inside div

Tags: css

I have what should be a very basic css question. I want to justify the text in this div just like it you'd see in a newspaper. I can't really understand why it refuses to do it.

Below is a codepen with the example i'm trying to do. I want all the letters to sit flush so it creates a box. Thank you!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPYJqo

```
<div id="where_we_are_factoid"><p>Corporate Learning<br>
Centers are located on<br>
<span>3 continents,</span><br>
in 4 countries and 27 states</p></div>

#where_we_are_factoid {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 200;
  float: right;
  width: 260px; 
}
#where_we_are_factoid p {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}
#where_we_are_factoid span {
  font-size: 39px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

Comment: Because you have `<br>`in your markup. You need to have plain text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084785/set-a-line-break-in-justified-text-and-still-have-it-justify

Comment: [Your code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVZKPb) without `<br>` tags.

Comment: `text-justify` is not supported in modern browsers

Comment: Reason you are not using a `<p>` for every line?

Comment: Using `<p>` for every line can't work, because justify is not applied on last line of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line-by-line justification can be done by adding extra mark-up, but the CSS is a bit complex.

Depending on the words in use and the overall width of the parent `div`, the typography can look a bit unpleasant, so some experimentation may be needed.

My example is a proof-of-concept, the actual use is still subject to comment and debate.

```css
#where_we_are_factoid {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 200;
  width: 260px;
  float: right;
}
#where_we_are_factoid span {
  text-align: justify;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.20em;
  height: 1.20em;
}
#where_we_are_factoid span:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 0;
}
#where_we_are_factoid span.bold {
  font-size: 39px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div id="where_we_are_factoid">
  <span>Corporate Learning</span>
  <span>Centers are located on</span>
  <span class="bold">3 continents,</span>
  <span>in 4 countries and 27 states</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This Ended up being the right way for me to control each line giving them each a different letter spacing and removing justify on the final line. Either way thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `text-justify` has long since been drooped from support

You need to think about how text formatting work's. When you use `<br>` you are committing a single line break ending that text string. So there is no additional space to justify to because that is where it end's.

The same happens for `<p>` wrapping them all in `<p>` will not work because you are telling it to stop there imagine how screwy a three word sentence would look justified to `500px`

The only way you are going to do it is by setting a fixed `width` and try to get it as close as possible to what you want like in the example below.

```css
#where_we_are_factoid {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 200;
  width: 220px; 
  float: right;
}
#where_we_are_factoid p {
  text-align: justify;
}
#where_we_are_factoid span {
  font-size: 39px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div id="where_we_are_factoid"><p>Corporate Learning
Centers are located on
<span>3 continents,</span>
in 4 countries and 27 states</p></div>
```

alternatively you could use multiple `span class`and pad the hell out of it to get it all lined up the way you want.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Couldn't get it to look exactly like i wanted so i did move to placing a span on each line. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped you out

Answer (score 0):

This question is along the same train of thought as another I answered - this may help you: [How to determine largest possible font-size such that it fits on one line in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322040/how-to-determine-largest-possible-font-size-such-that-it-fits-on-one-line-in-css/31322693#31322693)

If you don't mind using a javascript library, [fittext.js](http://fittextjs.com/) would accomplish what you are after well and work responsively (at different device widths). Definitely put each of your sentences in a seperate `span` element for structural integrity.

Looking at that other thread, another poster recommended using css `calc` and a monospace font which also works responsively: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVvWEW