# How can I format a paragraph with a <br /> tag in it as justified?

Tags: html, css

My Code:

```html
<h1>example</h1>
<p align="justify">John&rsquo;s family is living in a tiny flat. That would not be too bad. But unfortunately John is longing for a dog to play and fool arount with. There isn&rsquo;t any space for a dog in the small attic. How can John&rsquo;s dream come true? The little
  mermaid is searching for <br /> a friend who is exactly like her. Unfortunately she cannot find an other mermaid in the ocean. So she has to stay all alone. Or is there any solution for this problem?
</p>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2QB4.jpg):
The line with the `<br />` tag in it is not formatted as justified.

> It is important that all lines except the last are formatted as
> justified.
>
> The size of the gaps between the words is not important.
>
> The line break must remain exactly there.

I tried HTML and CSS.
I googled it and looked for a similar question here in the forum.
Without success.

---

***Self-found solution:***

With:

```
text-align: justify;
text-align-last: justify;
```

in CSS it works !!!

Comment: Seems weird it is not two paragraph tags.

Comment: @epascarello - It's like a poem. Every line break makes sense. But each paragraph should be represented as justified. - Plus the text comes from mysql via php and already has the line breaks in it.

Comment: Set a width and see the difference.

Comment: @Sam Herrmann - This question / answer is almost 6 years old and has the problem:  "However, if the rest of the paragraph does not fit on one line, it will overflow past the width you have set."

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63062369/8620333 ... the age of the quesiton doesn't matter, there is new answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another `<p>` tag around the last bit of text. You may or may not want to adjust the spacing between the paragraphs afterwards.

Also, you'll want to check the width of the parent element of your `<p>` tags. Depending on the parent element's width, it may or may not cause the text to wrap around to the next line.

```html
<body>
<h1>example</h1>
<p align="justify">John&rsquo;s family is living in a tiny flat. That would not be too bad. But unfortunately John is longing for a dog to play and fool arount with. There isn&rsquo;t any space for a dog in the small attic. How can John&rsquo;s dream come true? The little mermaid is searching for <br/></p>
<p align="justify"> a friend who is exactly like her. Unfortunately she cannot find an other mermaid in the ocean. So she has to stay all alone. Or is there any solution for this problem?</p>
</body>
```

Comment: If I have 3 sentences - each sentence in one line, each line should be justified. How do I do it?

Comment: How can I format one line as justified?

Comment: If you have each sentence take up one line, then I suggest making each sentence have its own `<p>` tag. That way, you can add `align="justify"` to each `<p>` tag.